# twitterStream not found

Tags: scala, twitter, apache-spark, spark-streaming

I'm trying to compile my first scala program and I'm using twitterStream to get tweets, here is a snippet of my code:

```
import org.apache.spark._
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._
import org.apache.spark.streaming._
import org.apache.spark.streaming.twitter._
import org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext._
import TutorialHelper._

object Tutorial {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {

    // Location of the Spark directory 
    val sparkHome = "/home/shaza90/spark-1.1.0"

    // URL of the Spark cluster
    val sparkUrl = TutorialHelper.getSparkUrl()

    // Location of the required JAR files 
    val jarFile = "target/scala-2.10/tutorial_2.10-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"

    // HDFS directory for checkpointing
    val checkpointDir = TutorialHelper.getHdfsUrl() + "/checkpoint/" 
    // Configure Twitter credentials using twitter.txt
    TutorialHelper.configureTwitterCredentials()
 val ssc = new StreamingContext(sparkUrl, "Tutorial", Seconds(1), sparkHome, Seq(jarFile))

        val tweets = ssc.twitterStream()
val statuses = tweets.map(status => status.getText())
    statuses.print()
    ssc.checkpoint(checkpointDir)
    ssc.start()
      }
    }
```

When compiling I'm getting this error message:

```
value twitterStream is not a member of org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext
```

Do you know if I'm missing any library or dependency?

Comment: What is so cryptic about -> `StreamingContext` has no member named `twitterStream`.

Comment: You can get a stream of tweets by using `org.apache.spark.streaming.twitter.TwitterUtils` which has a `createStream` method which takes `SparkStreamingContext` and twitter auth credentials as paramters.

Comment: @SarveshKumarSingh Can you please explain further how can I use TwitterUtils, please add a code snippet in a comment

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this case you want a stream of tweets. We all know that Sparks provides `Streams`.  Now, lets check if Spark itself provides something for interacting with twitter specifically.

Open Spark API-docs -> http://spark.apache.org/docs/1.2.0/api/scala/index.html#package

Now search for `twitter` and bingo... there is something called `TwitterUtils` in package `org.apache.spark.streaming`. Now since it is called `TwitterUtils` and is in package `org.apache.spark.streaming`, I think it will provide helpers to create stream from twitter API's.

Now lets click on `TwitterUtils` and goto -> http://spark.apache.org/docs/1.2.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ReceiverInputDStream

And yup... it has a method with following signature

```
def createStream(
                 ssc: StreamingContext,
                 twitterAuth: Option[Authorization],
                 filters: Seq[String] = Nil,
                 storageLevel: StorageLevel = StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK_SER_2
                ): ReceiverInputDStream[Status]
```

It returns a `ReceiverInputDStream[ Status ]` where `Status` is `twitter4j.Status`.

Parameters are further explained

**ssc**
StreamingContext object

**twitterAuth**
`Twitter4J` authentication, or `None` to use Twitter4J's default `OAuth` authorization; this uses the `system properties` `twitter4j.oauth.consumerKey`, `twitter4j.oauth.consumerSecret`, `twitter4j.oauth.accessToken` and `twitter4j.oauth.accessTokenSecret`

**filters**
Set of filter strings to get only those tweets that match them

**storageLevel**
Storage level to use for storing the received objects

See... API docs are simple. I believe, now you should be a little more motivated to read API docs.

And... This means you need to look a little( at least getting started part ) into `twitter4j` documentation too.

> NOTE :: This answer is specifically written to explain "Why not to shy
>   away from API docs ?". And was written after careful thoughts. So
>   please, do not edit unless your edit makes some significant
>   contribution.

Comment: One Last questions, when I'm using "None" in the auth field it is returning nothing no tweets. Will try to create new OAuth object with my twitter application credentials. Does that make sense?

Comment: If you specify None, it tries to find the Auth credentials in projects conf file. In your case you should  provide your own oauth object.